# Initialize jagged array of objects in C#

Tags: c#

I'm trying to create a board game for Tic-Tac-Toe on size 3X3-

[image]

I have `Cell` class with 2 properties:

1. Id
2. Value

The `Value` property type is `CellEnum` that include 3 situations:

1. empty (empty string)
2. player1 - for 'X'
3. player2 - for 'O'

Now, I've created new class called `Board` and inside of this class I want to create a `board` - a matrix (or jagged array) of cell objects.
How can I initialize the `board` object?

```
public class Board
{
    public Cell[][] board = 
    {
         ????
    }
}
```

Cell class-

```
public enum CellEnum
{
    empty = ' ',
    player1 = 'X',
    player2 = 'O'
}
public class Cell
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public CellEnum Value { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This way, for instance:

```
public Cell[][] board = {
    new Cell[]
    {
        new Cell()  {Id = 1, Value = CellEnum.empty}, 
        new Cell()  {Id = 2, Value = CellEnum.empty}, 
        new Cell()  {Id = 3, Value = CellEnum.empty}, 
    },
    new Cell[]
    {
        new Cell()  {Id = 4, Value = CellEnum.empty}, 
        new Cell()  {Id = 5, Value = CellEnum.empty}, 
        new Cell()  {Id = 6, Value = CellEnum.empty}, 
    },
    new Cell[]
    {
        new Cell()  {Id = 7, Value = CellEnum.empty}, 
        new Cell()  {Id = 8, Value = CellEnum.empty}, 
        new Cell()  {Id = 9, Value = CellEnum.empty}, 
    },
};
```

However, this is a jagged array shaped as a matrix. A real matrix should better be implemented with a 2D array.

As a final note, you asked how to init the jagged array you mentioned. If I'd have to model a simple game as Tic-Tac-Toe, maybe a flat list would make things easier.

Answer (score 0):

Since you will not change the size of Tic-Tac-Toe board you can initialize it as static size 2-dimensional array. Possible options below.

I also attach the Microsoft documentation:
[Jagged Arrays](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/jagged-arrays), [Multidemensional Arrays](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/multidimensional-arrays).

```
    public Cell[,] boardArrayWithDimentionsSpecified = new Cell[3, 3]
    {
        { new Cell { Id = 1, Value = CellEnum.empty}, new Cell { Id = 2, Value = CellEnum.empty}, new Cell { Id = 3, Value = CellEnum.empty} },
        { new Cell { Id = 4, Value = CellEnum.empty}, new Cell { Id = 5, Value = CellEnum.empty}, new Cell { Id = 6, Value = CellEnum.empty} },
        { new Cell { Id = 7, Value = CellEnum.empty}, new Cell { Id = 8, Value = CellEnum.empty}, new Cell { Id = 9, Value = CellEnum.empty} }
    };

    public Cell[,] boardArray = new Cell[,]
    {
        { new Cell { Id = 1, Value = CellEnum.empty}, new Cell { Id = 2, Value = CellEnum.empty}, new Cell { Id = 3, Value = CellEnum.empty} },
        { new Cell { Id = 4, Value = CellEnum.empty}, new Cell { Id = 5, Value = CellEnum.empty}, new Cell { Id = 6, Value = CellEnum.empty} },
        { new Cell { Id = 7, Value = CellEnum.empty}, new Cell { Id = 8, Value = CellEnum.empty}, new Cell { Id = 9, Value = CellEnum.empty} }
    };


    public Cell[][] boardJaggedArray = new Cell[][]
    {
        new Cell[] { new Cell { Id = 1, Value = CellEnum.empty}, new Cell { Id = 2, Value = CellEnum.empty}, new Cell { Id = 3, Value = CellEnum.empty} },
        new Cell[] { new Cell { Id = 4, Value = CellEnum.empty}, new Cell { Id = 5, Value = CellEnum.empty}, new Cell { Id = 6, Value = CellEnum.empty} },
        new Cell[] { new Cell { Id = 7, Value = CellEnum.empty}, new Cell { Id = 8, Value = CellEnum.empty}, new Cell { Id = 9, Value = CellEnum.empty} }
    };

    public Cell[][] boardJaggedArrayWithDimensionsSpecified = new Cell[3][]
    {
        new Cell[] { new Cell { Id = 1, Value = CellEnum.empty}, new Cell { Id = 2, Value = CellEnum.empty}, new Cell { Id = 3, Value = CellEnum.empty} },
        new Cell[] { new Cell { Id = 4, Value = CellEnum.empty}, new Cell { Id = 5, Value = CellEnum.empty}, new Cell { Id = 6, Value = CellEnum.empty} },
        new Cell[] { new Cell { Id = 7, Value = CellEnum.empty}, new Cell { Id = 8, Value = CellEnum.empty}, new Cell { Id = 9, Value = CellEnum.empty} }
    };
```